# How to search for the largest subset where every pair meets criteria?

Tags: algorithm, search, subset

I hope this isn't more of a statistics question...

Suppose I have an interface:

```
public interface PairValidatable<T>
{
    public boolean isValidWith(T);
}
```

Now if I have a large array of PairValidatables, how do I find the largest subset of that array where every pair passes the isValidWith test?

To clarify, if there are three entries in a subset, then elements 0 and 1 should pass isValidWith, elements 1 and 2 should pass isValidWith, and elements 0 and 2 should pass isValidWith.

Example,

```
public class Point implements PairValidatable<Point>
{
    int x;
    int y;

    public Point(int xIn, int yIn)
    {
        x = xIn;
        y = yIn;
    }

    public boolean isValidWith(Point other)
    {
        //whichever has the greater x must have the lesser (or equal) y
        return x > other.x != y > other.y;
    }
}
```

[The intuitive idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898787/finding-largest-subset-where-each-number-in-any-pair-one-number-is-divisible-by) is to keep a vector of Points, add array element 0, and compare each remaining array element to the vector if it passes the validation with every element in the vector, adding it to the vector if so... but the problem is that element 0 might be very restrictive. For example,

```
Point[] arr = new Point[5];
arr[0] = new Point(1000, 1000);
arr[1] = new Point(10, 10);
arr[2] = new Point(15, 7);
arr[3] = new Point(3, 6);
arr[4] = new Point(18, 6);
```

Iterating through as above would give us a subset containing only element 0, but the subset of elements 1, 2 and 4 is a larger subset where every pair passes the validation. The algorithm should then return the points stored in elements 1, 2 and 4. Though elements 3 and 4 are valid with each other and elements 1 and 4 are valid with each other, elements 2 and 3 are not, nor elements 1 and 3. The subset containing 1, 2 and 4 is a larger subset than 3 and 4.

I would guess some tree or graph algorithm would be best for solving this but I'm not sure how to set it up.

The solution doesn't have to be Java-specific, and preferably could be implemented in any language instead of relying on Java built-ins. I just used Java-like pseudocode above for familiarity reasons.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to run the same algorithm against each entry in the array, and return whichever one resulted in the most successful returns of isValidWidth when checked against all other entries?

Comment: @Stephan Not quite. Every pair in the subset should return true from isValidWith. For example, a might be valid with b and b might be valid with c but c might not be valid with a. That would mean either a or c would have to be omitted. I'm not sure if my example method would behave that way but the solution should include methods that would.

Comment: can you expand your question to include more than 3 entries in the example, and what you would expect the output to be?

Comment: Graphing this out, it looks like you're looking for the largest subset of elements who's edges have a non-negative slope. Does this sound accurate?

Comment: @Stephan that's a good observation, though I think you meant to say non-*positive* slope. This could make solving that case easier.

Comment: you're correct. I've been doing screen coordinates so much I was thinking of my reference in the top left, rather than the standard Cartesian bottom left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably `isValidWith` is commutative -- that is, if `x.isValidWith(y)` then `y.isValidWith(x)`. If you know nothing more than that, you have an instance of the [maximum clique problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumClique.html), which is known to be NP-complete:

Skiena, S. S. "Clique and Independent Set" and "Clique." §6.2.3 and 8.5.1 in The Algorithm Design Manual. New York: Springer-Verlag, pp. 144 and 312-314, 1997.

Therefore, if you want an efficient algorithm, you will have to hope that your specific `isValidWith` function has more structure than mere commutativity, and you will have to exploit that structure.

For your specific problem, you should be able to do the following:

1. Sort your points in increasing order of x coordinate.
2. Find the [longest decreasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) of the y coordinates in the sorted list.

Each operation can be performed in O(n*log(n)) time, so your particular problem is efficiently solvable.

Comment: So I guess I would set up a graph where each vertex represents an array element and the edges connect pairs that pass isValidWith?

Comment: @Devsman I have added a section to my answer discussing your particular `isValidWith` function.